# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE)

Tags: php, parsing, syntax, do-while

I can't fix this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in /xyz/xyz.php on line 76
```

I'm using php 5.4.4

Anyone could help?

The xyz.php 74-96 Lines:

```
if (( function_exists( 'get_magic_quotes_gpc' ) &&    get_magic_quotes_gpc(  ) )) {
    $process = array( &$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST );
    $val = while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {;
        [0];
        $key = ;

        if () {
            foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
                unset( $process[$key][$k] );

                if (is_array( $v )) {
                    $process[$key][stripslashes( $k )] = $v;
                    $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes( $k )];

                    continue;
                }

                $process[$key][stripslashes( $k )] = stripslashes( $v );
            }
        }

        unset( $$process );
    }
```

Comment: Your syntax for the while loop is odd - why are you trying to assign it to `$val`? What are `[0];` and `$key = ;` trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`while` is a language construct, and is NOT something you can capture a return value from:

```
$val = while ( ... ) { ... }
^^^^^^---invalid
```

It should be just

```
while (...) { ... }
```